# Use plugin multiple times

Tags: plugins

I have a site for a booking agency for entertainers. Each entertainer has their own page. The sidebar currently contains the advanced twitter profile widget for the agency's twitter account. Each of the entertainers' pages needs the same widget in their sidebar with their own account id.
Question is:
Is it possible to use the same plugin with different id's?
Or:
Must I create multiple sidebars (20 +) and hard code the plugin using the different account id's?

The hard code I have used that is suppose to mimic this plug falls short on functionality and cannot be styled to look identical to the widget.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the [Advanced Twitter Profile Widget Plugin](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/advanced-twitter-profile-widget/trunk/advanced-twitter-profile-widget.php?rev=327319) does not use the W[ordPress Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) and extend the WP_Widget class which would allow multiple instances of the widget.

Your best option is to find another Twitter Widget Plugin.  There are hundreds available.  I found one similar called [Twitter WidgetWidget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-widgetwidget/).

Install the [Widget Logic Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) which will create a meta box at the bottom of each widget for conditional statements on where to display it.

Drag one instance of the widget into the sidebar for each entertainer and add this to the widget logic box

`is_page('page_name')` using the slug from the page or use the page id.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, I think you hit it on the nose. Exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @sticks464 Great!  Since this worked for you it's helpful if you mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkbox on the upper left side of the entry.  This lets other users know what works and I get more points :)

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the plugin slightly, to load the content of a custom field as the Twitted ID, and on each clients page add a custom field with the client's Twitter ID.

Or else as you said create a sidebar per client (might be useful in the long run)